# Wikidata+SPARQL: lookup a company based on it's ticker symbol

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to lookup a company based on it's ticker symbol using sparql.

This query will list businesses and their tickers (basic query)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?ticker
WHERE {
    ?id wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q4830453 .
    ?id wdt:P249 ?ticker .
    ?id rdfs:label ?idLabel 
    FILTER(LANG(?idLabel) = 'en').
}
```

But, IBM is not included, because IBM has it's stock ticker placed 'inside' the P414 property (Stock exchange).

https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q37156

How can I expand this list to include companies with P414 and P249 tickers "inside" them?

Here is how I can show ibm is not included:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?exchange ?ticker2
WHERE {
    ?id wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q4830453 .
    ?id wdt:P249 ?ticker . FILTER(LCASE(STR(?ticker)) = 'ibm') .
    ?id rdfs:label ?idLabel 
    FILTER(LANG(?idLabel) = 'en').
}
```

Comment: That one gets all NewYorkStockExchange tickers: `?id p:P414 ?stock_exchange_statement .
    ?stock_exchange_statement ps:P414 wd:Q13677 .
    ?stock_exchange_statement pq:P249 ?ticker .`

Comment: Andy, thus, you should use something like `(p:P414/pq:P249)|(p:P249/ps:P249)` in place of `wdt:249`. Read more about Wikidata [qualifiers](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Qualifiers) and the whole [data model](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/Indexing/RDF_Dump_Format#Data_model).

Comment: Awesome !! Thanks for the help and the link !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So the answer based on [AKSW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4744359/aksw) and [Stanisla](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7879193/stanislav-kralin)v's comments are that THIS query will list all the stocks on the New York Stock Exchange (as long as the ticker is listed 'under' the exchange:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?exchange ?ticker
WHERE {
    ?id wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q4830453 .
    ?id p:P414 ?exchange . 
    ?exchange ps:P414 wd:Q13677 .
    ?exchange pq:P249 ?ticker .

    ?id rdfs:label ?idLabel 
    FILTER(LANG(?idLabel) = 'en').
}
```

And THIS query will find a specific stock (IBM) on the New York stock exchange:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?exchange ?ticker
WHERE {
    ?id wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q4830453 .
    ?id p:P414 ?exchange . 
    ?exchange ps:P414 wd:Q13677 .
    ?exchange pq:P249 ?ticker . FILTER(LCASE(STR(?ticker)) = 'ibm') .

    ?id rdfs:label ?idLabel 
    FILTER(LANG(?idLabel) = 'en').
}
```

And THIS query will find a specific stock on ANY stock exchange, OR referenced directly (Shown here with two different stock tickers to illustrate the search). This query is quite long because wikidata sometimes have the stock exchange sub field UNDER the ticker, and sometimes the other way around. Oh, and sometimes they are two different fields altogether (not linked). Oh Joy.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?id ?idLabel ?exchange ?exchangeLabel ?ticker
WHERE {
    ?id wdt:P31/wdt:P279* wd:Q4830453 .
    { 
       # Find cases where the ticker is the main attribute, and the exchange may be below it.
       ?id wdt:P249 ?ticker . FILTER(LCASE(STR(?ticker)) = 'nsu') .
       ?id p:P249 ?tickersub .
       ?tickersub pq:P414 ?exchange 
    }
    UNION {
       # Find the exchange and it's ticker 
       ?id wdt:P414 ?exchange . 
       ?id p:P414 ?exchangesub .
       ?exchangesub pq:P249 ?ticker . FILTER(LCASE(STR(?ticker)) = 'ibm') .
    } 
    UNION {
       # Find the exchange and it's ticker 
       ?id wdt:P414 ?exchange . 
       ?id wdt:P249 ?ticker . FILTER(LCASE(STR(?ticker)) = 'frme') .
    } 
    SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

Comment: How can I modify the code to search for a given ticker symbol AND a given stock exchange?