# Retrieve ticker of company with sparql

Tags: sparql, wikidata-query-service

The [Wikidata website](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:List_of_properties/Organization) gives an example of the `ticker symbol` property `P249`:

`Boeing <ticker symbol> BA`

I thought this should translate to the following sparql query:

```
PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#>
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>

SELECT ?ticker WHERE {
  wd:Q66 wdt:P249 ?ticker.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

However, when running this in the [Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20schema%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wikibase%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwikiba.se%2Fontology%23%3E%0APREFIX%20wd%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fentity%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0A%0ASELECT%20%3Fticker%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ66%20wdt%3AP249%20%3Fticker.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%2Cen%22.%20%7D%0A%7D), this yields no result.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48568094/search-wikidata-sparql-query-matching-sub-value#comment84149516_48568094

Comment: It's exactly the same...closed.